# Resetting redis keys daily using twisted

Tags: python, linux, redis, twisted, cronexpression

I am using twisted engine along with Redis. 
I need to clear some redis keys daily (at 12 oclock, to maintain day wise data).

I tried to use task.LoopingCall which works fine. It clears keys after 24 hrs but problem is, to work this, I need to start engine at 12 oclock. So LoopingCall can be set for 24 hrs.

Instead of starting engine at 12 oclock, is there any better way using twisted & redis themselves?

As per my knowledge, we can do this using crone job. But is it good or is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean you want to clear those keys at 12:00 AM *local* time, first you'll want to install the [`tzlocal`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tzlocal) package:

```
$ pip install tzlocal
```

and then you can compute the time until the next timezone, something like this:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone

zone = get_localzone()

import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now(zone)
next_midnight = (now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) +
                 datetime.timedelta(days=1))

delta = then - now
until_next_midnight = delta.total_seconds()
```

And finally, you can start your `LoopingCall` at that point, something like this:

```
call = LoopingCall(...)
reactor.callLater(
    until_next_midnight,
    lambda: call.start(datetime.timedelta(days=1).total_seconds())
)
```

Comment: Also getting direct answer fro Glyph, its really awesome. I forget to 'callback' words.